# Search a csv for a string and save that column

Tags: python, csv

Using pythons csv module, I'm trying to open a CSV file, search it for a specific string

in that file and once found, store that column. This is my way of reading columns now, but I

won't always know the specific column number that I want, so I need to search for a column

name instead.

```
with open('Work.csv','r') as f:
 reader = csv.reader(f)
 reader.next()
  for row in reader:
    for (i ,v) in enumerate(row):
      columns[i].append(v)
```

My csv looks like:

```
Default  Names  
  0        1
  2        3
```

Comment: What do you want to store, column number or data of that column?

Comment: I need to store just the data

Comment: Check out my solution then, may be that's what you wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import csv
columns = []                        #save the columns in this list
with open('myfile.csv','r') as f:
 reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
 ind = next(reader).index('Default')   #find the index of 'Default' in the header
 for row in reader:
     columns.append(row[ind])
```

Comment: Can I do, if 'name of cell' in col: for the condition

Comment: @trf5291 yes, but what is 'name of cell'?

Comment: I edited the question, so would I do if 'Default' in col: to save a list with [0,2]

Answer (score 0):

Create a list from the row and use index function on a list.

For example

a = 'one two three four'.split()

indexNum = a.index('three')

print indexNum  # which is 2